# Restructure table and check for values

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have one table (Table 1) which looks like below-

```
keys
AAB12B34
CC34DE5W
SEF5C6T4
SQA7ZZ87
LM24NO3P
X34YY78Z
```

And another table (Table 2) which looks like below-

```
category_id   category_name    associated_keys
    111          Books         CC34DE5W|SQA7ZZ87|LM24NO3P
    222          Office        LM24NO3P|AAB12B34
    444         Furniture      X34YY78Z|LM24NO3P|SQA7ZZ87|SEF5C6T4|CC34DE5W|AAB12B34
    222          Office        X34YY78Z
```

I want to do 2 tasks-

**Task 1:**

At any given point I want to have only one row for each category_id. If there are 2 rows (meaning if the id is repeated) then I want to group by category_id and add the associated_keys. So, out put of this table should look like-

Table 3-

```
category_id   category_name    associated_keys
    111          Books         CC34DE5W|SQA7ZZ87|LM24NO3P
    222          Office        LM24NO3P|AAB12B34|X34YY78Z
    444         Furniture      X34YY78Z|LM24NO3P|SQA7ZZ87|SEF5C6T4|CC34DE5W|AAB12B34
```

**Task 2:**

Then, I want to convert all values inside the **keys** field in **Table 1** into column names and then check **Table 2**. If a particular **category_id** has that key in **associated_keys** field then I want to add 1 underneath that key field else insert 0.

Finally, the result will look like-

```
category_id  category_name AAB12B34  CC34DE5W   SEF5C6T4    SQA7ZZ87   LM24NO3P   X34YY78Z
    111         Books         0          1         0            1          1          0
    222        Office         1          0         0            0          1          1
    444       Furniture       1          1         1            1          1          1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and accumulate all new nuances about your case - hope you will be able to make this new cleaned version to work for you (note: it is actually the same logic as in my initial answer, but with some correction to address column names starting with digits, using correct column name in Table1, etc)

```
DECLARE statement STRING;
SET statement = (
  WITH task1 AS (
    SELECT category_id, category_name, STRING_AGG(associated_keys, '|') AS associated_keys
    FROM `your_project.your_dataset.data` 
    GROUP BY category_id, category_name
  )
  SELECT '''
  SELECT 
    category_id,
    category_name, ''' || (
    SELECT STRING_AGG('IF("' || ids || '" IN UNNEST(keys), 1, 0) AS col_' || ids, ', ') 
    FROM `your_project.your_dataset.keys` 
    ) || ''' FROM task1, UNNEST([STRUCT(SPLIT(associated_keys, "|") AS keys)])'''
);
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '''
WITH task1 AS (
  SELECT category_id, category_name, STRING_AGG(associated_keys, '|') AS associated_keys
  FROM `your_project.your_dataset.data` 
  GROUP BY category_id, category_name
)''' || statement;
```

Above assumes below tables structure (and sample data)

```
`your_project.your_dataset.keys` AS (
    SELECT 'AAB12B34' ids UNION ALL
    SELECT '34DE5WCC' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'SEF5C6T4' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'SQA7ZZ87' UNION ALL
    SELECT '24NO3PLM' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'X34YY78Z' 
  ), `your_project.your_dataset.data` AS (
    SELECT 111 category_id, 'Books' category_name, '34DE5WCC|SQA7ZZ87|24NO3PLM|SQA7ZZ87|sample300|sample300' associated_keys UNION ALL
    SELECT 222, 'Office', '24NO3PLM|AAB12B34|X34YY78Z' UNION ALL
    SELECT 444, 'Furniture', 'X34YY78Z|24NO3PLM|SQA7ZZ87|SEF5C6T4|34DE5WCC|AAB12B34|sample200' UNION ALL
    SELECT 222, 'Office', 'X34YY78Z|sample100' UNION ALL
    SELECT 111, 'Books', 'AAB12B34' 
  )
```

if to apply code to above sample data

result is

```
Row category_id category_name   col_AAB12B34    col_34DE5WCC    col_SEF5C6T4    col_SQA7ZZ87    col_24NO3PLM    col_X34YY78Z     
1   111         Books           1               1               0               1               1               0    
2   222         Office          1               0               0               0               1               1    
3   444         Furniture       1               1               1               1               1               1
```

Comment: Works now. Thanks a lot. Really appreciate your efforts.

Comment: this query processes 2 statements and after running this query I have to click on View Results to see the result. Is there a way to save the results in some table automatically using the 'Query Settings' in big query and specifying the name of the table I want to store the results in?

Comment: sure. you can use DML's INSERT statement or DDL's CREATE statement as a part of EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

Comment: I am getting some errors in doing so. Will you be able to modify your answer to accommodate that? Happy to post a new question altogether if required. Thanks

Comment: i tend to not change/update my answers because of follow up question(s) - please post new question with all respective details and I will answer it when time allow :o)

Comment: I completely understand. No problem. will post a new question. Thanks!

Comment: each question - should be self-containing separate question - obviously you can provide reference to previous posts - but still - your question should be asked in a way that it has no dependency on anything else but the question body itself - otherwise it has high chance to be voted for closure as lacking focus/details - I suggest you to refine your new question

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

> Task 1

```
#standardSQL
SELECT category_id, category_name, STRING_AGG(associated_keys, '|') AS associated_keys
FROM `project.dataset.data` 
GROUP BY category_id, category_name
```

if to apply to sample data from your question as in below example -

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.data` AS (
  SELECT 111 category_id, 'Books' category_name, 'CC34DE5W|SQA7ZZ87|LM24NO3P' associated_keys UNION ALL
  SELECT 222, 'Office', 'LM24NO3P|AAB12B34' UNION ALL
  SELECT 444, 'Furniture', 'X34YY78Z|LM24NO3P|SQA7ZZ87|SEF5C6T4|CC34DE5W|AAB12B34' UNION ALL
  SELECT 222, 'Office', 'X34YY78Z' 
)
SELECT category_id, category_name, STRING_AGG(associated_keys, '|') AS associated_keys
FROM `project.dataset.data` 
GROUP BY category_id, category_name
```

output is

```
Row category_id category_name   associated_keys  
1   111         Books           CC34DE5W|SQA7ZZ87|LM24NO3P   
2   222         Office          LM24NO3P|AAB12B34|X34YY78Z   
3   444         Furniture       X34YY78Z|LM24NO3P|SQA7ZZ87|SEF5C6T4|CC34DE5W|AAB12B34
```

> Task 2   - using scripting feature of BQ and dynamically builds needed pivot statement and does not depend on number and names of keys thus eliminates manual building of select statement

```
DECLARE statement STRING;
SET statement = (
  WITH task1 AS (
    SELECT category_id, category_name, STRING_AGG(associated_keys, '|') AS associated_keys
    FROM `project.dataset.data` 
    GROUP BY category_id, category_name
  )
  SELECT '''
  SELECT 
    category_id,
    category_name, ''' || (
    SELECT STRING_AGG('IF("' || key || '" IN UNNEST(keys), 1, 0) AS ' || key, ', ') 
    FROM `project.dataset.keys` 
    ) || ''' FROM task1, UNNEST([STRUCT(SPLIT(associated_keys, "|") AS keys)])'''
);
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '''
WITH task1 AS (
  SELECT category_id, category_name, STRING_AGG(associated_keys, '|') AS associated_keys
  FROM `project.dataset.data` 
  GROUP BY category_id, category_name
)''' || statement;
```

when applied to sample data from your question - output is

```
Row category_id category_name   AAB12B34    CC34DE5W    SEF5C6T4    SQA7ZZ87    LM24NO3P    X34YY78Z     
1   111         Books           0           1           0           1           1           0    
2   222         Office          1           0           0           0           1           1    
3   444         Furniture       1           1           1           1           1           1
```

Comment: This gives an error. It says "Unrecognized name: key"

Comment: looks like typo or copy/paste error - give me a sec to double check

Comment: @user11035754 - I just double checked and confirming that my answer works  - for both Task1 and Task2. IMPORTANT - they assume existence of two tables `project.dataset.keys` (Table1) and  `project.dataset.data` (Table2) - so you need to replace those with your actual names - please do and let me know - should work! as I said I just double checked and getting result as in my answer

Comment: I did replace the table names and also fixed the "Unrecognized name: key" error. Now I am getting another error - Invalid EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql string `select category_id, category_name, IF(associated_keys LIKE "%AAB12B34%", 1, 0) AS AAB12B34,IF………..(for each keys) Syntax error: Missing whitespace between literal and alias at [x:y]

Comment: I suspect you could slightly adjust code while replacing  - please post your final code and I will show where is the problem - post as update to your question - don't use comment for this as formatting in comments gets lost but important to see it

Comment: Hey, btw. the code fragment in your last comment IS NOT from my answer  - so obviously it doe s not work!!! Can you please try code in my answer AS IS with correct tables names and let me know if it works! Don't mix it with the code from other answer(s) - which obviously might not work

Comment: I am getting an EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql error for your answer as well. In my original data I have some keys that start with a number. For example, 11BB6AA7. Can this be the problem?

Comment: of course!!! so change this line `SELECT STRING_AGG('IF("' || key || '" IN UNNEST(keys), 1, 0) AS ' || key, ', ') ` with `SELECT STRING_AGG('IF("' || key || '" IN UNNEST(keys), 1, 0) AS col_' || key, ', ') `  - here you just adding `col_` as a prefix to column alias thus avoiding error of name starting with digit. try and let me know  - it should be it! your example haven't exposed that issue so it was not handled in original answer - now with prefix  - it should

Comment: It still gives me the "Unrecognized name: key" error for this line -> SELECT STRING_AGG('IF("' || key || '" IN UNNEST(keys), 1, 0) AS col_' || key, ', ')

Comment: Would you be able to tell me what key refers to in this line? keys is the column name of Table 1. What is "key"?

Comment: `key` is the column name in the Table1! if in your real table this is named keys - just replace key with keys

Comment: Apologies for a poorly written question here. I realized what the problem could be and so updated and posted a completely new question covering all the use cases. 
Please check the new question here-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63681210/remove-duplicates-and-restructure-table-by-checking-values-between-two-tables

Comment: Also, I changed the field name of Table 1 from keys to ids to avoid some confusion.

Comment: Really appreciate your help. Thanks a lot

Comment: It isn't the same question. Refer to the Note in the new question. I think that is what is giving the error

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

**First Answer:**

```
SELECT
  category_id, category_name, STRING_AGG(associated_keys, "|") AS associated_keys
FROM
  dataset.table2
GROUP BY 
  category_id, category_name;
```

**Second Answer:**

> Standard SQL Option

```
select category_id,
       category_name,
       keys,
       IF(keys like '%AAB12B34%', 1,0) as AAB12B34,
       IF(keys like '%CC34DE5W%', 1,0) as CC34DE5W,
       IF(keys like '%SEF5C6T4%', 1,0) as SEF5C6T4,
       IF(keys like '%SQA7ZZ87%', 1,0) as SQA7ZZ87,
       IF(keys like '%LM24NO3P%', 1,0) as LM24NO3P,
       IF(keys like '%X34YY78Z%', 1,0) as X34YY78Z 
from (
select category_id, category_name, STRING_AGG(associated_keys, "|") keys from table2 group by category_id, category_name);
```

> Dynamic SQL Option

**Create a View:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW
  dataset.vw_table2 AS
SELECT
  category_id, category_name, STRING_AGG(associated_keys, '|') AS associated_keys
FROM
  dataset.table2
GROUP BY category_id, category_name;
```

**Create Dynamic SQL:**

```
DECLARE
  dynamicsql STRING;
SET
  dynamicsql = (
  SELECT
    'select category_id, category_name, ' || STRING_AGG('IF(associated_keys LIKE "%' || keys || '%", 1, 0) AS ' || keys, ',') || ' from dataset.vw_table2'
  FROM
    dataset.table1);
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  dynamicsql;
```

**Snapshot:**
[image: Result]

Comment: It gives the following error - Invalid EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql string `select category_id, category_name, IF(associated_keys LIKE "%AAB12B34%", 1, 0) AS AAB12B34,IF………..(for each keys) Syntax error: Missing whitespace between literal and alias at [x:y]

Comment: Added a snapshot of result