# Storing results of a stored procedure in a Google Big Query table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63642654/restructure-table-and-check-for-values/63681510?noredirect=1#comment113237836_63681510) to the question I asked earlier. The accepted answer works perfectly.

But this stored procedure processes 2 statements and after running this procedure I have to click on View Results of the second statement to see the result in Google Big Query. Is there a way to save the results in some table automatically using the 'Query Settings' in Google Big Query and specifying the name of the table I want to store the results in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot set a destination table for a script (or for call a procedure), instead, you can convert your `SELECT` statement into `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT`, for example:

```sql
SELECT 1 x;

=>

CREATE TABLE myDataset.myTable
AS SELECT 1 x;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a string parameter for your procedure. Then use this parameter in the dynamic query to write the results to the table.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `my_dataset.my_procedure`(destination_table STRING)
BEGIN

CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp AS SELECT 1 x;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (
    FORMAT("CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `%s` AS SELECT * FROM tmp", destination_table));

END
```

Now you can provide a table name and call this procedure to write the results to the table.

```sql
CALL `my_dataset.my_procedure`("my_dataset.my_table");
SELECT * FROM `my_dataset.my_table`
```